# Fix my (short) Python to C# Algorithm Port

Tags: c#, python, math, port

Writing a sorting algorithm based off of Reddit's here: http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588

I'm having a little trouble getting it all to fit together because some of the System.Math signatures differ in their application.

```
public class Calculation
{
    protected DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1);

    protected int EpochSeconds(DateTime date)
    {
        var td = date - Epoch;
        return td.Days*86400 + td.Seconds + ((td.Milliseconds)/1000000);
    }

    protected int Score(int upVotes,int downVotes)
    {
        return upVotes - downVotes;
    }

    public int HotScore(int upVotes,int downVotes,DateTime date)
    {
        var s = Score(upVotes, downVotes);
        var order = Math.Log(Math.Max(Math.Abs(s), 1), 10);
        var sign = Math.Sign(s); //Edit from Jonathon Reinhart
        var seconds = EpochSeconds(date) - 1134028003;
        return Math.Round(order + sign + *seconds/45000, 7);
    }
}
```

**Edits for more information**

Specifically I'm getting an error on the last line

```
return Math.Round(order + sign + *seconds/45000, 7);
//error "The * or -> operator must be applied to a pointer"
```

"

The closest match I can find in the method signature is this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377

Comment: What exactly is the question, or what issue are you having?

Comment: I'd like to check for general errors if possible, but I also added the specific build error.

Comment: Reddits has MICROseconds and you have MILLIseconds. Don't know if this is causing the problems, but it be one issue.

Comment: What is the exact compiler error you're getting?

Comment: I was told I may need to use this without context,
http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/07/10/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-a-.net-datetime.aspx

Comment: The * or -> operator must be applied to a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One recommendation I would make is to use [`Math.Sign(Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd3y5wdf.aspx). So:

```
var sign = new int();
if (s > 0) { sign = 1; }
else if (s < 0) { sign = -1; }
else { sign = 0; }
```

Becomes:

```
var sign = Math.Sign(s);
```

---

Ok, so you're having problems with this line:

```
return Math.Round(order + sign + *seconds/45000, 7);
```

Well for one, you're probably losing the fractional part in `seconds/45000`, because they are both `int`. Cast one to double first:  `((double)seconds / 45000)`.

For two, you've likely got a syntactical error `sign + *seconds`.  Do you mean `+` or `*`? It thinks you're using `seconds` like a pointer.

Finally, [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round) returns a `double`, but your `HotScore` method is returning an `int`. I'm guessing you want that to return a `double`.

My guess is that this is what you want:

```
public double HotScore(int upVotes,int downVotes,DateTime date)
{
    var score = Score(upVotes, downVotes);
    var order = Math.Log(Math.Max(Math.Abs(score), 1), 10);
    var sign = Math.Sign(score);
    var seconds = EpochSeconds(date) - 1134028003;
    return Math.Round(order + sign * ((double)seconds/45000), 7);
}
```

---

Also, I don't think your `EpochSeconds()` is correct. I adapted this from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/03/20/93332.aspx):

```
public long GetEpochTime(DateTime dt) 
{ 
    var ts = dt.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1970 8:00:00 AM")); 

    return ((((((ts.Days * 24) + ts.Hours) * 60) + ts.Minutes) * 60) + ts.Seconds); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can just swap the code? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywb0xks3.aspx seems to indicate yes.

Comment: Yes, note that I linked to the documentation, but for the `Int32` version, not the `double` version.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error on the last line - the sequence of `+ *` isn't valid. I think what you want for the last line is this (using [this `Math.Round` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby)):

```
return Math.Round(order + sign * ((double)seconds / 45000), 7);
```